# How do I calculate a user's grade in percentage?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make my game give the percentage(%) of a user's grade but I keep getting 0%.

Here's my code :

```
int win = 2
int Percentage = win/5;
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Your score is : " + win + "/" + "5" + "(" + Percentage *100 + "%" + ")");
```

**Console** : `Your score is : 2/5(0%)`

Comment: double Pourcentage = win/5.0;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use double (floating point) arithmetic for this. FYI / 5.0 converts the int into a double

```
double Pct = win / 5.0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!

Could you explain why using int doesn't work?

Comment: You could actually make int work (albeit to only two digit accuracy) by multiplying by 100 first. But otherwise integers are only (positive & negative) whole numbers and zero

Comment: can't I change let's change 20.0% into 20% instead?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. One is DecimalFormat. Another is printf

Answer (score 1):

The `Integer` type can only be whole numbers. If you want to create a percentage, you need to use the `Double` type.
You can also use `\n` to create a new return line in your printout.

```
double win = 2.0;
double percentage = (win/5) * 100;
System.out.println("\n\n Your score is: " + win + "/5 (" + percentage + "%)");
```

Comment: Double is not a type- it is a class. And double(the primitive) here is more appropriate than Double

Comment: I always forget to add \n to make newlines. Thanks! :)

Comment: @ControlAltDel you are right. My mistake. I made edits to use the double primitive.